# How to unit test with Java Swing JOptionPane Confirm Dialog

Tags: java, swing, unit-testing, joptionpane

I have a java swing application which expects the users to choose `YES` or `NO` from `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`

Since the JOptionPane stops the thread and is waiting for user input, my code is not automatically testable.

Is there anyway I can programatically get around this? Or simulate yes or no?

In my test now, a confirm dialog appears, where I have to push the yes or no button.

***Update***

I found a brilliant option.

I created an interface called `OptionPane` with basically all the different types of messages I need.
Then I created a default implementation that just relegates to the JOptionPane`s static methods. Then I created a YesMockOptionPane, that basically returns YES_OPTION for all the confirm messages, and a NoMockOptionPane for all the NO_OPTIONS.

Here is the code:

`<<usage>>`

```
class Foo {
  OptionPane optionPane = new DefaultOptionPane();

  public void someMethod() {
    if (optionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "choose yes or no", "Please confirm", 
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                return;

        //User pressed yes
  }    

  public void setOptionPane(OptionPane o) {
    this.optionPane = o;
  }
}

//Snippet of the interface
public interface OptionPane {

   int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
          Object message, String title, int optionType);
}

public class DefaultOptionPane implements OptionPane {
  @Override
  public int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
        Object message, String title, int optionType) {

      return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parentComponent,message,title,optionType);
  }
}

public class YesMockOptionPane extends DefaultOptionPane {
  //MockOptionPane is just an abstract class implementing default methods from OptionPane
  @Override
  public int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType) {
      return JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
   }
}
```

Now in the unit test I can simply set the appropriate MockOptionPane.

```
dialog.setOptionPane(new YesMockOptionPane());
```

Comment: Isn't it odd to unit test UI components?

Comment: Odd in what way? Odd in the sense that it is difficult, then yes, odd in the sense that you shouldn't do it, no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with (also copied in the question)

`<<usage>>`

```
class Foo {
  OptionPane optionPane = new DefaultOptionPane();

  public void someMethod() {
    if (optionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "choose yes or no", "Please confirm", 
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                return;

        //User pressed yes
  }    

  public void setOptionPane(OptionPane o) {
    this.optionPane = o;
  }
}

//Snippet of the interface
public interface OptionPane {

   int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
          Object message, String title, int optionType);
}

public class DefaultOptionPane implements OptionPane {
  @Override
  public int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
        Object message, String title, int optionType) {

      return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parentComponent,message,title,optionType);
  }
}

public class YesMockOptionPane extends MockOptionPane {

  @Override
  public int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType) {
      return JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
   }
}
```

Now in the unit test I can simply set the appropriate MockOptionPane.

```
dialog.setOptionPane(new YesMockOptionPane());
```

Answer (score 3):

The elegant way would be to modify the code to expect the answer from an interface, something like

```
public interface UserAnswer {
    boolean yesPressed();
}
```

and then implement it with JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog for production code, and hardcoded for test code.

If this is not possible, you can try to send events on the event dispatch thread to the JOptionPane with EventQueue.invokeLater.

Answer (score 1):

I thought there would be existing answers on this but I couldn't find any!

I think you need to create a layer of abstraction between your code and the JOptionPane.
This should be of the form of an interface with a method which will return to your code whether the user has chosen yes or no - you can call the method something meaningful such as 'isWantToOverwriteExistingFile' or similar.

The normal implementation of this interface would call your JOptionPane as you're doing now.
Your test will use a different implementation of this interface which will return a yes or no (without showing a JOptionPane) depending on which choice you wish the test to make.

Let me know if you need more details!